# Which of these selectors is faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, which is faster.

```
//option 1
var foo = $("#myForm .myOptionList option:selected").val();

//option 2
var foo = $("#myForm").find(".myOptionList option:selected").val();
```

Comment: Why don't you try benchmarking it yourself and see?

Comment: im going to guess option 1, `.find()` searches the entire DOM

Comment: You can benchmark that using jsperf.com and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about jsperf

Comment: If you have some sort of bottleneck here (I am guessing you don't), you should not be using selectors at all.

Comment: [Benchmark is here](http://jsfiddle.net/6VsxJ/).

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-perf-right-to-left)'s a test that suggest's using *find* and *children* is faster.